# QTabWidget: Unable to create a label on the tabbar to display tab name

Tags: qt5, qt-creator, qtabwidget, eglfs

I need to create a tabbar as shown in this image. I am able to create the tabs with only the icons and switch between them. However I am not able to create a `QLabel` in the tabbar to display the current selected tabname in the `Qlabel`.

[image: Tab bar design]

I am using the below code to add the label to the tabWidget, however the label does not show up when I run the code.

```cpp
tabName = new QLabel("Settings",(QWidget *)ui->tabWidget);
tabName->setFixedWidth(300);
```

Comment: The code shown is insufficient.  Please [edit] your question and state 1) what you're trying to achieve 2) what you've tried (preferably in the form of a [mcve]) and 3) the problem(s) you encountered.  Having said that, I suspect what you want can be achieved by placing the `QTabBar` and the `QLabel` in a [`QHBoxLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qhboxlayout.html).